# Wrapping Issue on IOS mail client

Tags: iphone, email, word-wrap

Mails in IOS mail client gets wrapped automatically. I want that wrapping to be stopped and I want my mail should be as its on browser or other email clients. I don't want a responsive layout.

I've tried adding a table with `width:600px` but that didn't help. Also I've tried adding `wrap:no-wrap` to the body and to the main `<div>` tag but that didn't help either.

Did anyone faced such type of problem. Kindly suggest what should be done here.

Comment: "Please provide a solution for this" is never well received here...

Comment: Did you really try  `wrap:no-wrap`, or is that just a typo here? It should be `white-space:nowrap`. I don't have an iPhone here, so I can't test. Also, you could test the HTML attribute `width="600"` instead of CSS.